# How can I connect webdriver to an instance of Edge on Android to run test scripts?

Tags: webdriver, adb, microsoft-edge

When running `msedgedriver --help` I get the following output:

```
Usage: C:\Users\Ian\.bin\msedgedriver.exe [OPTIONS]

Options
  --port=PORT                     port to listen on
  --adb-port=PORT                 adb server port
  --log-path=FILE                 write server log to file instead of stderr, increases log level to INFO
  --log-level=LEVEL               set log level: ALL, DEBUG, INFO, WARNING, SEVERE, OFF
  --verbose                       log verbosely (equivalent to --log-level=ALL)
  --silent                        log nothing (equivalent to --log-level=OFF)
  --append-log                    append log file instead of rewriting
  --replayable                    (experimental) log verbosely and don't truncate long strings so that the log can be replayed.
  --version                       print the version number and exit
  --url-base                      base URL path prefix for commands, e.g. wd/url
  --readable-timestamp            add readable timestamps to log
  --enable-chrome-logs            show logs from the browser (overrides other logging options)
  --allowed-ips                   comma-separated allowlist of remote IP addresses which are allowed to connect to MSEdgeDriver
```

The `--adb-port` option suggests in can connect to an [ADB](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb) server for debugging on Android.

I'm using the OpenQA Edge driver and trying to specify the ADB server port like this:

```
        // Initialize edge driver 
        var options = new EdgeOptions
        {
            PageLoadStrategy = PageLoadStrategy.Normal
        };
        options.AddArgument("adb-server-port=5037");

        _driver = new EdgeDriver(options);
```

When I try to connect it opens a desktop browser instead. What am I missing?

Comment: According to [this document](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#Enabling), you need to connect to the device via USB or WIFI before you can use the Android device for debugging. Did you perform these operations correctly?

Comment: @XudongPeng Yes, it's connected wirelessly using the Android 11 method